# Каково значение поговорки "Не мытьЁм, так кАтаньем"?

Tags: фразеология

Наверное, всем хорошо известно выражение  из  средневековья, которое и сегодня существует как поговорка: "Не мытьЁм, так кАтаньем".
Иногда по незнанию его связывают  со стиркой и глаженьем белья. Но только вот ни к стирке, ни к глаженью это выражение не имеет никакого отношения. Смысл его совершенно  иной.
"Мытом" на Руси называли пошлину за что-либо, взимаемую "мытарями" -- сборшиками пошлин. Отсюда глагол "мытарить" и выражение: "Терпеть всякие мытарства".
Что же касается слова "катанье", то оно происходит от слова "кат", что означает "рубАка, палач, мучитель" и поэтому "кАтанье" - мучение, пытка.
Таким образом, поговорка "Не мытьем, так катаньем" означает: "Не поборами, так мУками".

Comment: Хоть и не вопрос у вас, но прокомментирую. Во-первых, хочется увидеть источник столь оригинальной трактовки. И во-вторых, Непонятен общий смысл вашей версии. Чего это можно добиться не поборами, но муками? О сомнительностб использования слов "мытье" и "катанье" в ваших значениях, я выношу за скобки.

Answer (score 0):

В Интернете рассматриваются **три основные (наиболее частотные)** версии  фразеологизма, например:

http://chtooznachaet.ru/vyrazhenie_ne_mytem_tak_kataniem.html

https://www.esperanto-plus.ru/fraz/n/ne-mitjem.htm

По смыслу речевой оборот ближе **к следующему пониманию**: «Если подать не выплачивалась добровольно, то её выколачивали силой, должник попадал в руки палача – ката.  Получалось, если не отдашь добровольно, то заберем принудительно».

Версия про мытарей и палачей мне кажется верной, так как только в ней **четко выражено ПРОТИВОПОСТАВЛЕНИЕ**: если не получится одним способом, то используем другой.

Comment: противопоставление - это хорошо. Плохо то, что ни слово "катанье", ни слово "мытье" не зафиксированы в подобных значениях. Не говоря уж о том, что по форме это отглагольные образования - и если "к*а*тать" еще можно с грехом пополам свести к кату, то ни "мыть", ни гипотетическое "мытать" в эту схему совсем не укладываются.

Comment: *А этим словам и не надо никуда укладываться.* - ну да, зачем нам искать научные аргументы, когда очень хочется свести все к понравившемуся ответу?! Sharon, это несерьезно.  Мытье и Катанье могут быть образованы только от глаголов "мыть" и "катать". Как "бритье", "житье" и проч. Поэтому разговоры, что этим словам не надо никуда укладываться - это из области народной этимологии.

Comment: *а белье прокатывали, чтобы погладить, а не чтобы постирать* - а разве кто-то возражает?

Comment: Кстати говоря, зчем огород городить, изобретая объяснения через несуществующие в природе значения? Ваша трактовка передавалась бы обычной и понятной формой "Не мытарем - так катом". Зачем языку еще какие-то искусственные "мытье и "катанье"?